# Entity Framework - Temporal tables Race conditions last update not stored

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, temporal-tables

I am developing an ASP.NET Web API application using .NET Framework 4.8.

In the database, I am using the temporal tables features in SQL Server 2017 to track the changes of the stored rows. For data access, I am using Entity Framework as ORM. This seems to work fine, however, if I update a record, and directly afterwards delete the record using the code here:

```
_var recordForDelete = await _dbContext.record
                                       .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ID == id);

recordForDelete.LastModifiedBy = (int)SystemActions.System;

await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

_dbContext.record.Remove(recordForDelete);

await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The last update performed is not captured in the system versioning tables, the record is directly marked as deleted (by setting the system end time) missing the last update. It seems to be some sort of race condition, as adding a Task Delay between the two calls to `_dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()` solves the issue.

I also tried to change to `_dbContext.SaveChanges()` but this didn’t solve the problem.

Any recommendations on how to solve this issue?

Comment: You are missing AcceptAllChanges.  See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fa23068d-0e5d-41e5-b677-f4f94e3a99ad/writing-new-records-to-a-table-in-a-database-using-entity-framework-40?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: @jdweng There's no such method.  That 10-year-old post is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Have you used logging to ensure that the UPDATE statement is being sent?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I added an Entity Framework interceptor in order to log some information to a file using `LogInfo()` unfortunately, adding the logging statement fixes the behavior - after removing the logging statement in the interceptor (with the interceptor still beeing used) the race condition is back again and the last updates are missing. So I belive it really is entity framework trying to be smart.

Comment: Can you produce a small, self-contained repro of the issue?